# Is there a way to apply per-module view.yml constraints to foreign templates in Symfony 1?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

When doing the following, view.yml constraints in neither module a nor b take effect, whilst the 'all' config in module a does.

a/actions/actions.class.php

```
  public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->setTemplate('example', 'b');
  }
```

I have tried the following in both module a and b's view.yml's:

```
showSuccess:
  components:
    breadcrumbs: [sfDoctrineBreadcrumbs, breadcrumbs]

exampleSuccess:
  components:
    breadcrumbs: [sfDoctrineBreadcrumbs, breadcrumbs]
```

---

Just for completeness, I am trying to override the following in module a:

```
all:
  components:
    breadcrumbs: false
```

Taking out this condition does enable the component for the foreign template, but I'd rather now do this.

The all config of module b is also not applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's already loaded a view.yml at the point you call setTemplate, and don't think it'll load a second one.

I've used $this->forward instead of setTemplate before to get around the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately that requires the template to have it's own action, and cancels execution of the current action and breaks the breadcrumbs I'm trying to load in too. Perhaps the easiest solution is to force this stuff in from the existing action, assuming that's possible?

Comment: There's an event you can listen to ... may be able to do something.

Comment: Had a look at those but nothing seemed suitable / easy, opted for inverting the view.yml so that breadcrumbs are default, ta anyway!